# Oracle: Best practice to handle Flag

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

I have designed an ER diagram for a DVD shop which allows rentals only to registered customers and purchases can be from anyone. A DVD can obviously cannot be rented after it is purchased.

Every DVD can be purchased or bought.

**Question:**

What is the best way of enforcing in the database that a DVD cannot be rented after it is purchased.

**My Solution:**

I have a Sold_flag in DVD which is a Char(1 byte). It stores a one if it is sold and a zero if available purchased or rent. So if its a one it cant be rented.

Similarly if a DVD is being rented it has a flag. Storing one if it is rented and zero if is available to rent or purchase.

Are these two flags the best approach at dealing with these issues?

I am string them as char(1 byte) is this the best way of storing them ?

Situation:

Member (**Member_Num**, Name, Address, Telephone_Num, Join_Date)

DVD (**DVD_ID**, Film_ID, Sold_Flag,Rented_Flag)

Rental (**Member_Num, DVD_Num, Rented_On**, Returned_On, Price, Fine)

Purchase (**DVD_ID**, Member_Num, Price, Sold_On)

Film (**Film_ID**, Director, Name, Rent_Price, Sale_Price)

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the flag at all? You can just as well say "if retal exists on DVD it can't be purchased" - and vice versa.

Comment: @JensKrogsboell is exactly right. For your final use case, if there is an active rental (any matching rental where returned_on is NULL) disallow rental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate flags for sold and rented since these two states are mutually exclusive. If a DVD is sold, it can't be rented at the same time; similarly vice versa. Maybe a better substitute is a 'Status' kind of column which would say 1-Available, 2-Rented and 3-Sold. Maybe a lookup table for the different statuses.

You would have to enforce this rule programmatically though, because the rule applies to the "process of Renting", not on the static data that represents facts about the DVD or rentals or the customer.

You are basically saying that - "While renting, if someone chooses a DVD that is already sold, don't allow the rental transaction".

Because of that, in your procedure/function that says

```
PROCEDURE RENT_DVD (member_num, dvd_id, rented_on, price)
```

there would be an check in the beginning something like

```
FUNCTION is_dvd_rentable(dvd_id) return boolean
```

to confirm that the status of the DVD is not 3.

You might be tempted to put the logic in a trigger which might say something like 'if status=3 then don't allow this rental transaction to complete". But if you frequent this site or other oracle related webites like asktom, you would know that business logic should never be put in triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that in your diagram you replace entities Purchases and Rentals with a single Orders entity.

On the Orders entity you put an orderType property of either "purchase" or "rental".

Simple database constraints can enforce that a DVD can only appear on a single order line.

So:

Customer has Order on DVD.

Order is of Type.

Comment: Good idea. Although I think multiple tables could help OP define the entities better. In a single Orders table, you would have columns like rented_on, returned_on, late_fine, sold_on, etc. which are only applicable to their respective type of orders, not on all types of orders. You are probably breaking some data normalization rules when you have included attributes that don't define your data structure.

Comment: Maybe a supertype-subtype situation would be helpful. Orders as the supertype. Define the unique constraint in the orders table, and go to the subtypes and get the other attributes

Comment: @ruudvan you can keep the processing details in two separate tables depending on ordetType - eg. PurchaseOrderDetails and RentalOrderDetails: "Order has either PurchaseOrderDetails or RentalOrderDetails."